# Using CAM::PDF For Perl - Can I Read Text From A (v1.7) Password-Protected PDF File?

Tags: perl, cam-pdf

I noticed the CAM::PDF Perl module is built to read the text from a PDF file. Right now I have CAM::PDF v1.59 installed. I've successfully used it to read text from a (v1.2) PDF file that is *not* password protected, but when I try to open a (v1.7) password-protected PDF file using this code...

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use PDF::API2;
use CAM::PDF;
use CAM::PDF::PageText;

my $file = 'C:\Users\gwilliams\Documents\PWS20130517new.pdf';

my $pdf = CAM::PDF->new($file, '-', '-', 's3cretpasswd', fault_tolerant => 1)
  or die "$CAM::PDF::errstr\n";

my $pageone_tree = $pdf->getPageContentTree(1);

print CAM::PDF::PageText->render($pageone_tree);
```

... I receive the error message:

```
Invalid xref stream: could not decode objstream 3085
```

The attributes of the PDF file itself are:

- Version:         1.7
- Security Method: Password Protection
- Printing:        Not Allowed
- Fill In A Form:  Not Allowed
- Commenting:      Not Allowed
- Manage Pages:    Not Allowed
- Modify Document: Not Allowed
- Content Copying: Not Allowed
- Extract Contents: Not Allowed
- Signing:        Not Allowed

For what it's worth - it looks like the PDF in question was created with Adobe PDFMaker 10.1 for Excel.

What gives? Am I doing this right - or is the PDF incompatible with CAM::PDF?

Sincerely,
Confused

Comment: Documentation for CAM::PDF claims it is mostly compatible w/ PDF v1.5.  PDF versions 1.6 & 1.7 both added encryption options.  This may be an issue.

Comment: Read under Data Manipulation in the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm the author of CAM::PDF. It's probably an newer PDF feature that CAM::PDF doesn't support. I wrote the encryption support back in PDF 1.2 days and have barely updated it since. So most likely it's not your fault but is a limitation of the library.

Comment: OK. Good to know - direct from the source at that. I wove in pdftotext.exe (reluctantly) to handle the conversion, but it'd obviously be a lot cooler to handle that part from within Perl exclusively.